# How to awk unique line and print 2 lines above

Tags: linux, awk, hp-ux

I am facing an issue where I am using awk to find a line and print two lines above

Inside the file test.txt file is below"

```
{ TABLE "sacro".issue row size = 149 number of columns = 9 index size = 0 }

{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }

create table "sacro".issue
( 
issue_no serial not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue00,
user_logged varchar(8,1) not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue01,
issue_status_code integer not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue02,
issue_cat_code varchar(2) not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue03,
issue_descr text not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue04,
issue_feedback text,
user_action varchar(8,1),
date_logged date not null constraint "sacro".nnc_issue05,
date_compl date
);

revoke all on "sacro".issue from "public" as "sacro";

{ TABLE "sacro".issue_category row size = 104 number of columns = 2 index                        size = 8 }

{ unload file name = issue00107.unl number of rows = 5 }

create table "sacro".issue_category
(
issue_cat_code varchar(2) not null constraint "sacro".nnc_iss_cat00,
issue_cat_descr varchar(100),
primary key (issue_cat_code)  constraint "sacro".pkc_issuecategory
);

revoke all on "sacro".issue_category from "public" as "sacro";

{ TABLE "sacro".issue row size = 149 number of columns = 9 index size = 0 }

{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }
```

The line I am searching for is below:

```
create table "sacro".issue
```

The command I am running is:

```
cat test.txt | awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {for (i=f-B;i<=f+A;i++) print a[i]}' B=2 A=0 s='create table \"sacro\".issue'
```

When I run the command it finds the line create table "sacro".issue_category. Is there a way to grep for the line I need as if I was using grep -w. Unfortunately the below grep command does not work on HPUX:

```
cat test.txt | grep -B 2 -w "create table \"sacro\".issue" | head -1
```

My desired outcome should be (using head -1):

```
{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '
   1N                                  # get 2nd line in pattern space
   $!N                                 # get 3rd line in pattern space
   /\ncreate table "sacro"\.issue$/P   # if the last portion of matches, show 1st portion
   D                                   # strip 1st portion & reapply sed code on what
                                       # remains of the pattern space
' test.txt

grep -B 2 'create table "sacro"\.issue$' test.txt | sed q
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no reason why `grep` can't do this. Oh, and note that you don't need `cat`, both `grep` and `awk` can take input file names:

```
$ grep -xB2 'create table "sacro".issue' file
{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }

create table "sacro".issue
```

So, if you just want the first line there, do:

```
$ grep -xB2 'create table "sacro".issue' file | head -n1
{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }
```

The `-x` means "match the entire line" which ensures that the `create table "sacro".issue_category` line isn't printed. The `-B2` means "print the 2 previous lines as well.

---

You can also do it in `awk` as requested:

```
$ awk -vs='create table "sacro".issue' '($0==s){print b2}{b2=b1; b1=$0}' file 
{ unload file name = issue00106.unl number of rows = 74 }
```

Comment: This awk seems to work, but not with a file that has plenty table structures